# OfficeApp manifest permissions element failed while installation

Tags: xml, outlook, office-js

When uploading my OfficeApp manifest to get installed to Outlook add-in, I get the following error:

'The app list for the mailbox can't be read for the following reason: The value of the //owe1_1:Permissions element, ReadWriteDocument, is invalid..
OK'

when my permission is:

```
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
```

and when I change it to ReadWriteMailbox I get the following:

This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1:Permissions' element is invalid - The value 'ReadWriteMailbox' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed... The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1:Permissions' element is invalid - The value 'ReadWriteMailbox' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed. The Enumeration constraint failed.'

and here is the changed permission:

```
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
```

However it works in the Word by `ReadWriteDocument` permisson normally, How can I resolve it?

And here is the full manifest file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>da977793-c2c9-41e3-86f9-27c6889cf9e5</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="OfficeApp1" />
  <Description DefaultValue="OfficeApp1"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/taskpane_32x.png" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="DocumentEvents" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="File" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="Selection" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="Settings" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="TextFile" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="TextCoercion" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="TextBindings" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="BindingEvents" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/App/Home/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OfficeApp manifest sample provided doesn't follow the schema for an Outlook add-in. While the example did update the permissions to ReadWriteMailbox there are additional differences between and Outlook and Word manifest. I've updated the sample so it will install for Outlook.  Some of the updates made were to the xsi:type, Requirements, Host Name, and the inclusion of FormSettings.  For more information on how to construct a manifest for an Outlook add-in you can visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>da977793-c2c9-41e3-86f9-27c6889cf9e5</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="OfficeApp1" />
  <Description DefaultValue="OfficeApp1"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://remoteAppUrl/Images/taskpane_32x.png" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
   <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/App/Home/Home.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
</OfficeApp>
```

Note: The example provided here doesn't include the version overrides section which is required to submit an add-in to the store and our recommendation for all Outlook add-ins.

Comment: So can I create a project that works for both Word and Outlook?

Comment: No the same xml manifest cannot be used for both Word and Outlook.  Additionally, the Office.JS APIs that are available between the two applications also differ.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So the best way to create a project working with both is OfficeApp one and create additional manifest file so that I have 2 manifests files one for each? May you recommend me other solutions please?

Comment: That is correct. Since both applications use different APIs, you will need 2 separate manifests and projects